# I can't figure out how to make my Plotly charts show whole numbers only

Tags: python, plotly

[image of plotly chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DF3Eq.jpg)

Hello, I'm really struggling to figure out how to format the axes on this chart. I've gone through the documentation and tried all sorts of different formatting suggestions from here and elsewhere but really not getting it. As you can see, the bottom chart has a .5 number, I want that to be skipped altogether and only have whole numbers along the axis.

I've seen ,d as a tickformat option to do this in about every answer, but I can't get that to work or I'm not seeing how to apply it to the second chart.

Can anyone with some Plotly charting experience help me out?

Here's the pertinent code:

```
def create_chart():
#Put data together into an interactive chart
fig.update_layout(height=500, width=800, yaxis_tickprefix = '$', hovermode='x unified', xaxis_tickformat =',d',
                  template=symbol_template, separators=".", title_text=(df.columns[DATA_COL_1]) + " & Units 2015-2019"
                  )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what is happening is that the `xaxis_tickformat` parameter is affecting only the first subplot, but not the second one. To modify the formatting for each subplot, you can pass a dictionary with the `tickformat` parameter to `yaxis`, `yaxis2`, .... and so on for however many subplots you have (in your case, you only have 2 subplots).

```
import pandas as pd
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

## recreate the df 
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year':[2015,2016,2017,2018,2019],
    'Sales':[8.8*10**7,8.2*10**7,8.5*10**7,9.1*10**7,9.6*10**7],
    'Units':[36200,36500,36900,37300,37700]})

def create_chart():
    #Put data together into an interactive chart
    fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=df.Year, 
        y=df.Sales, 
        name='Sales',
        mode='lines+markers'
    ), row=1, col=1)

    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=df.Year, 
        y=df.Units, 
        name='Units',
        mode='lines+markers'
    ), row=2, col=1)

    fig.update_layout(
        title_x=0.5,
        height=500, 
        width=800, 
        yaxis_tickprefix = '$', 
        hovermode='x unified', 
        xaxis_tickformat =',d',
        ## this will change the formatting for BOTH subplots
        yaxis=dict(tickformat ='d'),
        yaxis2=dict(tickformat ='d'),
        # template=symbol_template, 
        separators=".", 
        title={
            'text':"MCD Sales & Units 2015-2019",
            'x':0.5
        }
    )
    fig.show()

create_chart()
```

[image]

Comment: OH MY GOD, thank you so much. I've spent months off and on trying to solve this and I either just never saw that I could just say yaxis2 or didn't find it in my searching.

Seriously, thank you so much Derek. You are a gentleman and a scholar who deserves everything you want. 

THANK YOU

Comment: Haha I'm glad to have helped - thanks for accepting!